# Explicitly specify sort order for MySQL query (use an "IN" list)

Tags: mysql, query, order-by

With a query like the following, the default will return in order of id of least to greatest even if the `IN` list is not in that order. In my situation the list will be supplied from some c# code.

How can I order the result set by the order of values in the `IN` list?

What I have:

```
SELECT * FROM example Where Id in (1,3,2);
returns: 
|---------------|---------------|
|       id      |    Value      |
|---------------|---------------|
|       1       |   example1    |
|---------------|---------------|
|       2       |   example2    |
|---------------|---------------|
|       3       |   example3    |
|---------------|---------------|
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM example Where Id in (1,3,2)
         Order By "Magic code here";
returns: 
|---------------|---------------|
|       id      |    Value      |
|---------------|---------------|
|       1       |   example1    |
|---------------|---------------|
|       3       |   example3    |
|---------------|---------------|
|       2       |   example2    |
|---------------|---------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=deb851192cd658e22e303df47fceb0c3)):

```
CREATE TABLE ex
(
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO ex (value) VALUES
('example1'), ('example2'), ('example3');
```

And then the "magic sauce"...

```
SELECT * FROM ex ORDER BY field (id, 1, 3, 2);
```

Result:

```
id  value
1   example1
3   example3
2   example2
```

This is a non-standard MySQL "trick".

A standards compliant way of doing this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM ex
ORDER BY 
  CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 1
    WHEN 2 THEN 3
    WHEN 3 THEN 2
  END;
```

Result:

```
id  value
1   example1
3   example3
2   example2
```

See the PostgreSQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=008d2fc4901443a6b29e795f42ddc6f0). PostgreSQL is one of the (possibly **the**) most standards compliant RDBMS systems out there, so that's why I used it for comparison purposesl

p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was wondering, is it particularly intensive to create a table like that(this will be called many times over)? Which one of these is faster? Or are they both similar enough in speed that it doesn't matter? p.s. glad to be here :D

Comment: It's difficult to say which is better - my gut tells me it's probably the MySQL "trick" - if you look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec15c928ef4af7758dd02db37e630750), you will see that (at least for me) that it's marginally faster - however, the `PRIMARY KEY` is ignored (unsurprising for such a small table) - so your guess is as good as mine. You should test using your own data!

Comment: (See also `FIND_IN_SET()` for some other situations.)